# patchvalue doesn't map the value in angular

Tags: angular

I have 2 forms stated below

```
this.checkoutForm = this.fb.group({
      addressForm: this.fb.group({
        firstName: [null, Validators.required],
        lastName : [null, Validators.required],
        addressLine1: [null, Validators.required],
        addressLine2: [null],
        stateId: [null, Validators.required],
        cityId: [null, Validators.required],
        pinCode: [null, Validators.required],
        mobileNumber: [null, Validators.required],
        emailAddress: [null, Validators.required]
      }),
      deliveryForm: this.fb.group({
        deliveryMethod: [null, Validators.required]
      })
    });
```

on ngInit Method, i am fetching the address and populating the address form

```
this.accountService.getUserAddress().subscribe(address => {
      if(address) {
        this.checkoutForm.get('addressForm').patchValue(address);
      }
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

The json result looks like below.

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "userid": 1,
        "firstName": "xxxx",
        "lastName": "xxxxxx",
        "addressLine1": "XXXXX",
        "addressLine2": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "stateId": 3,
        "stateName": null,
        "cityId": 4,
        "cityName": null,
        "pinCode": "xxxxx",
        "mobileNumber": "xxxxxx",
        "emailAddress": "xxxx@gmail.com",
        "enabled": true
    }
]
```

However the form is returned empty.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to patchvalue the `address[0]` something like this: `this.checkoutForm.get('addressForm').patchValue(address[0])`

Comment: Thank you ashot. its working. Its silly mistake from my side.

Comment: sometimes it happens, don't worry. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to **patchValue** in **form**.

```
  this.accountService.getUserAddress().subscribe(address => {
      if(address) {
       this.checkoutForm .patchValue({
      addressForm: {
        firstName: address.firstName,
        lastName : address.lastName,
        addressLine1: address.addressLine1,
        addressLine2: address.addressLine2,
        stateId: address.stateId,
        cityId: address.cityId,
        pinCode: address.pinCode,
        mobileNumber: address.mobileNumber,
        emailAddress: address.emailAddress,
      }
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Infact the address is an array. so taking the first element worked. i.e this.checkoutForm.get('addressForm').patchValue(address[0]);

Comment: can you post the data here of address, so that i can edit the answer as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If `getUserAddress()` return a valid `json` then your code should work. However, here is a demo for you to cross-check:

> app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient){}

  private readonly URL = 'https://reqres.in/api/users/2';

  checkoutForm = this.fb.group({
    dataForm: this.fb.group({
      email : [null, Validators.required],
      first_name: [null, Validators.required],
      last_name: [null],
      avatar: [null, Validators.required]
    }),
    addressForm: this.fb.group({
      company: [null, Validators.required],
      text: [null, Validators.required],
      url: [null, Validators.required],
    })
  });


  ngOnInit(){
    this.getData().subscribe(res => {
      this.checkoutForm.get('dataForm').patchValue(res.data);
      this.checkoutForm.get('addressForm').patchValue(res.ad);
      console.log(this.checkoutForm.value);
    });
  }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.URL);
  }
}
```